# how list USA as a first option from countries dropdown in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, country-codes

i have a countries dropdown in my rails app (using countries gem)

listing all the countries in the dropdown like this.

```
all_countries = ISO3166::Country.all.map{ |c|  ["#{c.alpha3} (+#{c.country_code})", c.country_code] }
```

i want to make US country as first option in the dp. for that I'm deleting that country and re adding the same at the first position like below, in order to show that country as first option(its working fine. but is there a better approach than this?)

```
all_countries.delete(["USA (+1)", "1"])

all_countries.unshift(["USA (+1)", "1"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort_by` and check if the element is equal to `"USA"`, if so, it goes first:

```
ISO3166::Country
  .all
  .map(&:data)
  .pluck('alpha3', 'country_code')
  .sort_by { |alpha3, _| alpha3 == "USA" ? 0 : 1 }
  .map { |alpha3, country_code| ["#{alpha3} (+#{country_code})", country_code] }

# [["USA (+1)", "1"],
#  ["JAM (+1)", "1"],
#  ["HTI (+509)", "509"],
#  ...
```

Or you can just partition all the countries when `alpha3` is equal to `"USA"`, and then flatten that result (I think that one is much better):

```
ISO3166::Country
  .all
  .map(&:data)
  .pluck('alpha3', 'country_code')
  .partition { |alpha3, _| alpha3 == "USA" }
  .flatten(1)
  .map { |alpha3, country_code| ["#{alpha3} (+#{country_code})", country_code] }
# ["USA (+1)", "1"], ["TJK (+992)", "992"], ["JAM (+1)", "1"], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all_countries.insert(0, all_countries.delete_at(all_countries.index("USA (+1)", "1")))
```